# How to set LD_PRELOAD for su or sudo?

Tags: linux, centos, glibc, su

I am working on CentOS 6.5. The version of my glibc is 2.14, and I accidentally link /lib64/libc.so.6 to a previous glibc(libc-2.12.so).

Then I run `export LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libc-2.14.so`, most commands can be executed except `su` and `sudo`. When run `su`, it gives *"Segmentation fault"*. When run `sudo`, it gives *"su: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib64/libcrypt.so.1)"*.

How to set `LD_PRELOAD` for `su` and `sudo`, or what can I do to recover the glibc?

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libc-2.14.so sudo -i` should do the trick, right?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Are you asking how to change the libc.so.6 symlink back to 2.14 glibc? This can be trivially done with ln. What you likely want to do is reinstall the package. I don't follow the su/sudo bit either - these programs are setuid and the loader will ignore the env var if executed by an unprivileged user, i.e. you really need to fix the actual problem.

Comment: @employeeofthemonth To use `ln` or a package manager, the victim would have to run `su` or `sudo`. Back to square one.

Comment: Boot from a recovery thumb drive and restore the damaged file.

Comment: I thought they are root already or sudo itself works - why else would 'su' segfault? I suspect they do 'sudo su', while they can do 'sudo bash' instead.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way, by design. Setting LD_PRELOAD allows arbitrary code to be executed within the executable. It would be rather unwise to allow that while running a sensitive prvileged SUID program.

Comment: correct -- glibc internally (in its ldso) will clear `LD_PRELOAD` and similar env vars whenever a set*id program (like su or sudo) are executed specifically to prevent security problems.  should mark this as the answer ;).

Answer (score 1):

> what can I do to recover the glibc?

This is a sysadmin question, more appropriate for serverfault, but one way to recover is:

1. Boot from a rescue CD
2. Mount root partition into /mnt
3. Fix the symlink
4. Reboot